# Python - Construct a Derived class using a classmethod from its Base class

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method

I have a base class `Polygon` which holds a collection of vertices. It can also be constructed using the classmethod `from_number_of_vertices_and_edge_length`, in which case an equilateral polygon is constructed.

I also have a derived class, `Square`. I'm trying to initialize `Square` using the classmethod of `Polygon`.

When I try to create a `Square` instance, it will go into `Polygon.from_number_of_vertices_and_edge_length()` with `cls` being `Square` instead of `Polygon`, causing the line `cls(vertices)` to fail because it's calling `Square(vertices)` whereas I require it to call `Polygon(vertices)`.

How can I solve this?

```py
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, vertices: list[Point]):
        self.vertices = vertices

    @classmethod
    def from_number_of_vertices_and_edge_length(cls, num_vertices, edge_length):
        # Create equilateral polygon with 'n' vertices.
        vertices = ...
        return cls(vertices)


class Square(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, edge_length):
        self.edge_length = edge_length
        super().from_number_of_vertices_and_edge_length(4, edge_length)
```

EDIT 1:
I'd like the square instance to end up with attributes `edge_length` and `vertices`.

Comment: The instance of `Square` has already been created by the time `Square.__init__` is called. It's not clear how best to organize this. For example, how does `Polygon.from_...` use the edge length passed as an argument?

Comment: Also, the class method assumes a particular signature for `__init__` which your subclass violates.

Comment: I'm fairly new to classmethods and sublcassing in general so excuse me. `Polygon.from_...` creates an n-gon where each edge has length `edge_length`.

Comment: This may be a lack in my understanding, but a subclass does not need to have the same signature as its base class correct?

Comment: The only real answer to your last comment is "kinda". Python won't force you to give the `__init__` methods the same (or compatible) signatures. But if you don't have a compatible signature, the subclass violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which means it can't be used in every situation the parent class could be used. It's up to you to decide if you care about violating LSP or not. In most situations, `__init__` doesn't need to be substitutable, but classmethod alternate constructors is one case where it does matter.